# when trying to nomalize a power plot , do we normalize it after converting it to db scale or before it?

Tags: power-spectral-density, normalization

I have two power plots. I am trying to normalize it for comparing them . So , do we normalize it after converting to db scale? or do we normalize the power as such?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference - you can multiply by a factor before log conversion or you can add a dB offset afterwards - mathematically it's equivalent.